# Working mechanism of a mass driver

Tags: mass-driver

Lately, i have been working on a school space report about space settlements. Transporting low mass payloads from the moon to the space settlement using a mass driver would be quite a affordable thought. To utilize this technology I need a deep understating about it, However I am unable to get a proper explanation about the machine's working mechanism. Can somebody help me out.

Apparently, I know that a mass driver uses electromagnetism to propel projectiles at extreme velocities.
Currently I am referring  the book : A design study - space settlements by Gerard.K O'Neill
I have attached the link for the book below:
[The link](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2016/ph240/martelaro2/docs/nasa-sp-413.pdf)

Comment: There's roughly as many ways to build a mass driver as there's ways of building a motor. Are you specifically only interested in the linear types (vs. centrifugal slings)?

Comment: I suspect you will find more information by looking at maglev trains.  It's only a matter of scale--trains are bigger, mass drivers work at much higher acceleration--but the concepts are the same.